# How to find quadratic vertex form function given a point?

Tags: quadratics

Write an equation of a parabola that has a directx of y= -5 and a focus at (2,-1)?

I'm guessing focus here means the vertex

$$ Y = a(x-h)^2 + k$$
$$-5 = a(x-2)^2 -1$$
$$-5 + 1 = a(x-2)^2$$

If i take the -4 to the other side than it would be 
$$0=a(x-2)^2+4$$
and the given answer choice doesn't have any of this 
How would i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The focus is not the vertex. The vertex is the midpoint of the line segment connecting the focus with the directrix and perpendicular to the directrix.   Geometrically, a parabola is the set of all points that are equidistant from a fixed point called the focus and a fixed line called the directrix.